# Publish React App onto Github Page but Shows Blank Page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github, github-pages

I have successfully uploaded a simple react app onto GitHub page using gh-pages, and now I'm trying to import the Shards dashboard project(https://github.com/DesignRevision/shards-dashboard-react) onto my GitHub page but it only shows a blank page.

Below is information I have so far:

1. My GitHub project and page address are

https://github.com/HarveyLijh/Company_ESG_Rating_App
https://harveylijh.github.io/Company_ESG_Rating_App/

2. The Shards dashboard project runs perfectly on my local
3. My package.json looks like this
   [image]

4. My chrome inspect window looks like this
   [image]

5. I have run the `npm run deploy` to build, and it runs perfectly without error
6. I uploaded my newly-created build folder onto my GitHub repo from the last command

why is this happening?

Comment: it happens because of base url of files if you keep `"homepage": "."` in package.json, it should work, and `browserRouter` doesn't works well in github static site, you can use `hashRouter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how URLs work. URL is a path that point to some specific resource on server. But how to locate that resource specified by a URL is totally up to the server to interpret. This interpretation is termed as "resolution".

Server can naively map the URL to the local filesystem path to a physical file on hard-disk. E.g. `http://localhost/foobar/dist/index.html` is likely pointing to somewhere like `/etc/www/foobar/dist/index.html` if you’re running nginx or apache server.

It can also be a in-memory file that’s generated on-the-fly by server. Php server typically does that. `http://localhost/home.php` is not a physical HTML file on disk. But the server generate HTML content on requested.

#### Now there’s another approach in the middle ground, which explains your situation.

The server can resolve the main path:

- https://harveylijh.github.io/Company_ESG_Rating_App/

and all its sub-paths:

- https://harveylijh.github.io/Company_ESG_Rating_App/foo
- https://harveylijh.github.io/Company_ESG_Rating_App/foo/bar
- https://harveylijh.github.io/Company_ESG_Rating_App/zoo

all these paths point to the same `index.html` file at:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HarveyLijh/Company_ESG_Rating_App/gh-pages/index.html, which is a physical file on disk.

The server only sends the same HTML to the browser. When browser finished loading the page, JS steps in, readd the URL in your address bar, and further decides which "state", or "route", should be rendered inside the React app.

That's how `BrowserRouter` works.

Browser exposes the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) to JS. With that API, JS can control the URL displayed in address bar, **without** actually go away to another page. In other word, the default behavior of entering URL in address bar and hit ENTER key is disabled temporarily. All that time you all just viewing the same `index.html` file.

To support `BrowserRouter`, github page service must first support the aforementioned behavior of resolving sub-paths to the same `index.html`, but unfortunately this is not configurable.

#### Solution

There's an easy hack: just copy your `index.html` and rename it to `404.html`!

Cus all sub-paths resolution would fail, and github page will resort to displaying `404.html`, and voila, problem solved!

For more detail of this hack, see: https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this problem happens but changing browserRouter to MemoryRouter